# How to use the DataConnectionDialog with a Oracle provider?

Tags: .net, oracle

I'm testing a `WinForms` app which shows the `DataConnectionDialog` to configure a connection to a *Oracle DataBase*.
The code I'm using:

```
  var oracleDataSource = DataSource.OracleDataSource;
  oracleDataSource.Providers.Add(DataProvider.OracleDataProvider);
            
  var dcd = new DataConnectionDialog();
  dcd.DataSources.Add(DataSource.OracleDataSource);
  DataConnectionDialog.Show(dcd);
```

But I need to use the new `Oracle Database (ODP.NET, Managed Driver)` provider. But in the DataProvider enum I don't have this option. Does anyone know how to add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it working by a few changes in the old Microsoft code. 
You can find my code at: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DAA8B744A27752C5!531&authkey=!AIxn6V0X3uM1NFE&ithint=file%2c7z

When you open the dialog use the following snippets to add the ODP.NET provider:

```
using OracleConnectionProperties = ConnectionUIProviders.OracleConnectionProperties;
using OracleConnectionUIControl = ConnectionUIProviders.OracleConnectionUIControl;


        DataConnectionDialog dialog = new DataConnectionDialog();
        DataSource.AddStandardDataSources(dialog);
        var p = new Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.DataProvider("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", "Oracle ODP.NET",
            "Oracle ODP.NET", "Oracle ODP.NET Oracle Data Provider for .NET",
            typeof(Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection), typeof(OracleConnectionUIControl),
            typeof(OracleConnectionProperties));
        var oracleProviders = dialog.DataSources.Single(x => x == DataSource.OracleDataSource).Providers;
        oracleProviders.Clear();
        oracleProviders.Add(p);
```